# Proper way to calculate order via entity framework / sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is this a good way to set the transaction level to serializable? If I set a lower transaction level, I will get duplicate orders. What is better approach? I assume this method will be invoked frequently by different users.

Here is my code

```
using (var tran = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
{
    try
    {
        var lastDocument = context.Documents.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        int order = 1;
        if (lastDocument != null)
        {
            order = lastDocument.Order + 1;
        }
        var document = new Document
        {
            CreatedDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Order = order
        };
        context.Documents.Add(document);
        context.SaveChanges();
        tran.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tran.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Is this a good way to set the transaction level to serializable?` Does it work?

Comment: `order = lastDocument.Order + 1;` This screams "terrible idea". Why are you not using an `IDENTITY` column?

Comment: @mjwills 1.Works but slowly 2.Because user can change order in spa application, it's something like drag and drop ordering

Comment: Why would the user care what the order number is? The database should generate it - not the application.

Comment: `1.Works but slowly` Sounds like serializable to me. :)

Comment: you're right identity column is best choice, thanks